# Can someone explain me how does this work ? How at the same time im using the string and the integer whit only one variable?

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, int, new-operator

```
using System;

namespace Cake
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int lenght = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int width = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int cakeSize = lenght * width;

            while(cakeSize>0)
            {
                ***string taken = Console.ReadLine();
                if(taken =="STOP")***

                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{cakeSize} pieces are left.");
                    return;
                }
                ***cakeSize = cakeSize - int.Parse(taken);***
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"No more cake left! You need {Math.Abs(cakeSize)} pieces more.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"How at the same time im using the string and the integer whit only one variable?"_ You should give more details about this. I do not understand what you mean with  _"whit only one variable"_.. because `lenght`, `width`, `cakeSize` and `taken` are all different variables.

Answer (score 2):

Since C#6 you can interpolate string with use of $ sign.
When you are writing

```
$"{cakeSize} pieces are left."
```

The compiler automaticly knows, that it should use toString on cakeSize and then cancatenate it with the rest of string. It is so called synax sugar

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question, you are confused how you use the string `taken` as an int when calculating `cakeSize`. this is possible because of the `Parse` method of `int`. what it does is, it takes a string and if possible it returns a new int value, so "12" becomes 12. 
in your case you can think of it this way:

```
cakeSize = cakeSize - int.Parse(taken);
```

is the same as writing:

```
int takenAsInt = int.Parse(taken);
        cakeSize = cakeSize - takenAsInt;
```

i hope this helps

Comment: I'm glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question kindly elaborate it more. I thought you are saying that you want to use one variable which can use as String and int as same time. If yes then try this :

```
// i is compiled as an int
var i = 5;

// s is compiled as a string
var s = "Hello";

// a is compiled as int[]
var a = new[] { 0, 1, 2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are wondering how ***taken*** is sometimes compared to **STOP** and after that is taken as a number:

```
    string taken = Console.ReadLine();
    if(taken =="STOP")
       {...}
    cakeSize = cakeSize - int.Parse(taken);
```

The trick here lies in the int.Parse() method. The console application reads the input as a string, so the user the first time can write **1** ("1") which can be converted to **int** with the help of int.Parse(). If the user writes **STOP** then the program exists and it never gets to the int.Parse() method. If the user writes  **ouch** (or something else) then the program will crash since it is different then "STOP" (it will not terminate the program) and the int.Parse() method won't be able to interpret the meaning of the "ouch" string.

Answer (score 0):

The ReadLine function of the console always returns a string object, and what you can do is convert it to a number through the Parse method, the problem with your catch is you had a return and the message cannot be displayed:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int lenght = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                int width = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                int cakeSize = lenght * width;

                while (cakeSize > 0)
                {
                    string taken = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (taken == "STOP") 

                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{cakeSize} pieces are left.");

                        break;
                    }
                    cakeSize = cakeSize - int.Parse(taken); 
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"No more cake left! You need {Math.Abs(cakeSize)} pieces more.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

have to control the errors with try catch {}, the user can enter any value of type strigne.

```
                try
                {

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think If I understand correctly from the question, you are trying to understand how `console.readline()` since it takes string and is storing it in a int type datatype.
For that you need to understand `int.Parse()` and how it works, so basically `int.Parse()` will convert your string to integer as the name suggest, so that mathematical calculations can be carried out, since they are only perform able on numerical datatypes and cannot be done on string, in case the conversion is not possible this will throw an error.

Hope this is what you are looking for!